# Strange errors While validation and uploading iOS application

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode8

I am trying to upload an application to the App Store.

During validation, it shows the following error:

> iTunes Store operation failed.

[image: validating]

During uploading, it shows:

> Web service content-type is not application/json
>   Could not connect to Apple's web service.

[image: uploading]

Comment: can be a problem with apple servers or the process. try it in few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be your network connection issue, also try uploading via Application Loader.

Comment: I tried uploading it through Application Loader.It shows the same Errors.

Comment: That's strange. turn off any anti virus if you have any, also check if your provisioning profiles are not invalid.

Comment: No antivirus is installed on my Mac.I tried removing and adding provisioning Profiles .That also Doesn't make any change.

Comment: Everything seems ok then... I guess it's because of your network, try with another network connection.. if that fails too, maybe apple servers are not responding well at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much MRFrhn.It was the Problem with my network.I switched the network and it worked.